# QR code scanning does not work in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I'm using ZXing.Net.Mobile and have the following code to scan the QR code.

```
await scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
{
   if (t.Result != null)
       HandleScanResult(t.Result);
});

scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
scanner.ScanContinuously(async (res) =>
{
    var msg = "Found Barcode: " + res.Text;

    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        ViewHelper.showMessage(msg, "");
    });
});
```

I've tried both ContinueWith and ScanContinuosly but none of them work.
I get a camera view with red line but it does not scan the QR code.

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: first line of code bothers me a lot

Comment: Okay I solved this by uninstalling the nuget and adding the required projects from https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile manually. 
Also updated the Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform. I'm guessing there is some issue with the current nuget package. Hope they fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using the [ZXing.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net/) package?

Mike Taulty wrote a whole blog post series on an app with Scanning on Windows 8.1, then porting it to Windows 10 and even running it on [HoloLens](https://mtaulty.com/2016/12/28/windows-10-uwp-qr-code-scanning-with-zxing-and-hololens/). The final post also has a small companion app that runs on UWP for simple scanning (with speech to command the app to scan).

In that sample, he's using following method:

```
ZXingQrCodeScanner.ScanFirstCameraForQrCode(
    result =>
    {
      this.txtResult.Text = result?.Text ?? "none";
    },
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

> There’s an assumption that the first camera found on the system should be used for QR code scanning but the classes that underpin this would allow for taking a more flexible approach and that ScanFirstCameraForQrCode function expands out into the following steps below

```
public static class ZXingQrCodeScanner
{
  public static async void ScanFirstCameraForQrCode(
    Action<Result> resultCallback, 
    TimeSpan timeout)
  {
    Result result = null;

    var mediaFrameSourceFinder = new MediaFrameSourceFinder();      

    // We want a source of media frame groups which contains a color video
    // preview (and we'll take the first one).
    var populated = await mediaFrameSourceFinder.PopulateAsync(
      MediaFrameSourceFinder.ColorVideoPreviewFilter,
      MediaFrameSourceFinder.FirstOrDefault);

    if (populated)
    {
      // We'll take the first video capture device.
      var videoCaptureDevice =
        await VideoCaptureDeviceFinder.FindFirstOrDefaultAsync();

      if (videoCaptureDevice != null)
      {
        // Make a processor which will pull frames from the camera and run
        // ZXing over them to look for QR codes.
        var frameProcessor = new QrCaptureFrameProcessor(
          mediaFrameSourceFinder,
          videoCaptureDevice,
          MediaEncodingSubtypes.Bgra8);

        // Remember to ask for auto-focus on the video capture device.
        frameProcessor.SetVideoDeviceControllerInitialiser(
          vd => vd.Focus.TrySetAuto(true));

        // Process frames for up to 30 seconds to see if we get any QR codes...
        await frameProcessor.ProcessFramesAsync(timeout);

        // See what result we got.
        result = frameProcessor.QrZxingResult;
      }
    }
    // Call back with whatever result we got.
    resultCallback(result);
  }
}
```

Source:

- [Mike Taulty's blog post](https://mtaulty.com/2016/12/28/windows-10-uwp-qr-code-scanning-with-zxing-and-hololens/)
- [Sample app on GitHub](https://github.com/mtaulty/QrCodes/blob/master/TestAppXaml2D/MainControl.xaml.cs#L50-L56)

I hope this approach helps you forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my  ready solution:
[Barcode_Scanner_UWP on GitHub](https://github.com/programmersommer/Barcode_Scanner_UWP)

I'v tried to make adoption of [VideoScanZXingWinRT](https://github.com/stepheUp/VideoScanZXingWinRT) repo

Both of them are using ZXing.Net
But in compare with old Mike Taulty [sample](https://mtaulty.com/2015/08/11/m_15904/) could catch QR "on the fly"